# Faking a time stamp from time.time() in Nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, timestamp, nose

I'm building a device object to poll data from connected devices in python and I'm trying to test the inter workings of the object and all it's functions using nose. I am running into a problem in general when writing a timestamp using `time.time()` as each time the function is called the result the value is different and this seriously screws up some test, for example this data collection function:

```
def getData(self, data):
    if type(data) is not type({}):
        #print "Bad Type!"
        raise TypeError
    else:
        #print "Good Type!"
        self.outD = {}
        datastr = ""
        for key, value in data.iteritems():
            self.outD[key] = value
        self.outD["timestamp"] = time.time()
        self.outD["id"] = self.id
        self._writeCSV()
```

When I test the output of this function and compare the generated CSV file, it always fails due to the time stamp. I can sub it out in my device object by adding testing flags, but I was wondering if nose has a built in way to deal with issues like this where the result of a function can be substituted with a given value or a local function to fake the `time.time()` call. Is this possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html). Example:

```
import time
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch('time.time', mock.MagicMock(return_value=12345))
def test_something():
    assert time.time() == 12345
```

Produces the following output:

```
$ nosetests3 -v
test.test_something ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.006s

OK
```

Despite the fact that `mock` is part of the `unittest` package, it's actually unrelated and works with any testing framework.

For Python < 3.3, you can use the [`mock` package from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock).

Comment: I'd rather stick to just using nose if possible.

Comment: @Dom: you can still use nose. My example refers to nose. If you want to use only nose, then the answer is either "you can't" or "write your own mock module"

Answer (score 6):

This is derived from the prior answer by A.C. It is not necessary to explicitly create a `MagicMock`. Secondly, the mock's use is conventionally asserted to ensure its usage.

```
import time
import unittest.mock

@unittest.mock.patch('time.time', return_value=12345)
def test_foo(mock_time):
    assert time.time() == 12345
    mock_time.assert_called_once()
```

This was tested with Python 3.7.

Comment: I don't believe that "the mock's use must also be asserted." It certainly *may* be, and depending on the test that could be important, but the test won't fail if it's not.

Comment: Note that creating the MagicMock instance allows you to avoid passing the mock to the test function. This is handy if you don't need to explicitly assert on the time call

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign the time.time() function to your own function and define with your own function the time in the appropriate manner:

```
time.time = my_time_function
```

The assignment to the own function can happen on the beginning of a unit test, while at the end the original function is restored again:

```
class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def get_time(self):
        return self.emulated_time

    def setUp(self):
        # Define the emulated time
        self.emulated_time = time.mktime(
                time.strptime("2020-01-18 02:02:05", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

        # Register the time.time function and patch it then
        self.time_method = time.time
        time.time = self.get_time

    def tearDown(self):
        # Restore the time.time function
        time.time = self.time_method
    
    def test_time_span(self):
        # Register the start time, do something, emulate a time update of 1
        # second, and check that the execution duration is one second
        start_time = time.time()
        # <do something here>
        self.emulated_time += 1
        self.assertEqual(time.time(), start_time+1)
```

This example was tested on Python 3.6.8.